# Navigation bar color in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-navigation-bar

I have a problem with the navigation bar color in android 13, when I set it to white the button remain white so they are not visible. Any solution to that in Kotlin? Can the button color in the navbar?
The color is set in themes.

Also I found some answers, either it's outdated or it does not work for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> add this to themes.xml

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navigation_bar_color</item>
```

> colors.xml

```
<color name="navigation_bar_color">#000000</color>
```

Comment: Yes this changes the nav bar color, but what about the buttons/icons? They stay white and are not visible

Comment: <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>

Comment: So that is kinda true, but the android studio requires min sdk 27 to work, so i had to use "        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(requireActivity().window, requireActivity().window.decorView).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = true
" and it worked for me

Comment: if my code was useful for you could you please tick the check